# How to get Nuxt.js environment variables defined in `env` object?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I have an .env file like so:

```
WP_API_PREFIX=somevalue
WP_ROOT=somevalue
```

Then in my nuxt config like so:

```
require('dotenv').config();

export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    env: {
        WP_ROOT: process.env.WP_ROOT,
        WP_REST_API_ENDPOINT: `${process.env.WP_ROOT}${process.env.WP_API_PREFIX}`
    },
```

Then down in my config file, I'd like to reference the `WP_REST_API_ENDPOINT` object, but I don't know how.

I have tried with:

process.env.WP_REST_API_ENDPOINT

But that is undefined.

How can I use the env I have set in the `env` object in `nuxt.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

In each page or layout, you may have asyncData:

```
export default {
  asyncData({ env }) {
    return { env }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to use it inside Nuxt.config.js not a component

Comment: Try `this.env` and inform the result.

Comment: I can't debug `this.env` since it is inside the nuxt.config.js. But if I try to assign `this.env.WP_REST_API_ENDPOINT` it is undefined.

Comment: No need to assign, just use the value. And use `console.log` instead of debugging.